# Navigating between controllers with TransitionManager

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewanimation, transition

I want to navigate back from second controller to first one, without using segue, but instead I have `@IBAction` connected to my back button, below is code for this method:

```
let deviceStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
let deviceDashView = deviceStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstView") as! 
self.navigationController!.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(deviceDashView, animated: true)
```

As you can see I'm trying to attach my own `TransitionManager`. I created it because I want to have transition animation like "from left to right" and by default it's opposite.

I know how to attach my TransitionManager if I change view with segue, but tried different configuration for `navigation controller`and none seems to work.

Where do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more complicate, what you will need is first to grab the viewcontroller you want to segue to and setup like this when the button is click:

```
var presenterStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let vc = presenterStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
{
    self.isPresenting = false //this flag helps to find the end of the transition
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
    vc.transitioningDelegate = self
    self.presentViewController(vc , animated: true)
    {
        self.isPresenting = false
     }
}
```

After that you will need to create a class responsible for the animation, this class implements the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and has the methods necessaries for the transition:

```
class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate  {

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        // get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view that we should perform the transition in
        let container = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {
                //Create your animation here
            }, completion: { 
                finished in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
}

// return how many seconds the transition animation will take
func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.5
}

// return the animataor when presenting a viewcontroller
// remmeber that an animator (or animation controller) is any object that aheres to the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
}

// return the animator used when dismissing from a viewcontroller
func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
}
```

Remember that the views from and to depend in the direction you going, from Master to detail from is Master to is the detail, however when you dismiss the detail it will invert and the from will be the detail and the to will be the Master

Comment: is that correct?:
    vc.transitioningDelegate = self

shouldn't it be reference to my TransitionManager?

Comment: No, the example is correct, the TransactionManager implements the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and the view controller executing the transition should set this delegate to itself as in the example. I just copy and past here from a working login form I have in one of my apps

Comment: When I set it to self I'm getting an error at a line with     vc.transitioningDelegate = self:

 Cannot assign a value of type 'MyControllerWithButton' to a value of type 'UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate?'

Also, where should I put that flag "isPresenting" in my Controller class or in TransitionManager ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issues